# WiFi card on new build is not recognized by Linux Mint 17.3

Tags: wifi, drivers, iwlwifi

I just completed a desktop build and installed Linux Mint 17.3 and the PCIe WiFi card is not being detected at all. The card is a [Gigabyte GC-WB867D-I](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00HF8K0O6).

There is nothing that recognizes the device to be present but missing a driver, but rather it is like there is nothing there at all.

I used Ethernet to perform all the recommended updates in the software center, and opened the driver manager and it told me that no devices were installed. I have also tried moving to a different PCIe slot on the motherboard and encountered the same symptoms.

I also read in the Amazon reviews of the WiFi card that it uses the Intel 7260AC chip, and so I downloaded the iwlwifi driver that I found on the Intel website and `cp`'d it into `/library/firmware` and rebooted. I don't know if that accomplishes anything or not.

I have also run `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware` and `sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree`.

Finally, here are the results of `lspci`

```
lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Host Bridge/DRAM Registers (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Sky Lake Integrated Graphics (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H USB 3.0 xHCI Controller (rev 31)
00:14.2 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H Thermal subsystem (rev 31)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H CSME HECI #1 (rev 31)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SATA controller [AHCI mode] (rev 31)
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #17 (rev f1)
00:1b.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Root Port #19 (rev f1)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev f1)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev f1)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev f1)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #5 (rev f1)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f1)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H LPC Controller (rev 31)
00:1f.2 Memory controller: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H PMC (rev 31)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H HD Audio (rev 31)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Sunrise Point-H SMBus (rev 31)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1083/1085 PCIe to PCI Bridge (rev 04)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 15)
06:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 (rev 3a)
```

Here is the [full parts list](http://pcpartpicker.com/user/benmordecai/saved/xdCj4) of the build:

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net` is:

```
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a) Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
```

Comment: The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` ?

Comment: `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
06:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wireless 8260 [8086:24f3] (rev 3a)
 Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:1010]
[2]+  Done                    unetbootin`

Comment: Don't post command output, scripts/source code, or sample data in comments.  Edit your question and add it there.  Remember to use the `{}` to format it as code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [wireless.wiki](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi) the Intel® Wireless 8260 device is supported by the **kernel 4.1** and later ,

Install `build-essential` and `linux headers`

download `iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz` from [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi)
Type the following command:

```
tar -zxvf iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0.tgz
cd iwlwifi-8000-ucode-25.30.13.0
sudo cp iwlwifi*.ucode /lib/firmware/
```

Download backport from [here](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/) example:

```
wget https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/stable/v4.3/backports-4.3-1.tar.gz
```

Unzip it and compile the `iwlwifi` module:

```
cd backports-4.3-1
make defconfig-iwlwifi
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot

Comment: But if you have 4.1 or layer, do you need these steps?

Comment: @AaronFranke Just copy the firmware to `/lib/firmware/`.

Comment: @Gryu welcome, you don't need to compile backports just copy the microcode to `/lib/firmware/` then run `sudo modprobe -rv iwlwifi`  and `sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi`

Comment: @Gryu You can update initramfs through `sudo update-initramfs -u`

Comment: Ok. Thanks for that explanation! But what I'm curios about is why backports installing cuts off working drivers? Does installation through compilation makes currently working drivers not working making links to newly compiled and installed drivers?

Answer (score 0):

I was having issues compiling:

```
make defconfig-iwlwifi
```

so I had to add:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential
```

which resolved my problems and the reboot got everything working.